# How can I build a switching circuit that scales several 12v signals down to <5v?

Tags: switches, automotive

Let me start off by saying that I know just enough about electronics to be dangerous (how to solder, follow a simple schematic, and check for connectivity problems and usually figure out what each wire is for).

I've installed a cruise control kit in my car, and I want to use a set of Honda steering wheel controls instead of the stock controls from the kit.  The cruise kit controls are expecting 12 volts, but I'm not comfortable running any more than 5 volts through the small steering wheel wires next to the airbag wiring.  I'd prefer even less, like 2-3 volts.

So I need to build a switching circuit that will provide the 12 volt signals to the cruise kit.  I was thinking of keeping it solid-state, since I don't know of any relays that will switch on 2-3 volts.  However, if there's a good reason to use relays then I can.

Here's a rough drawing of what I need:

[image: schematic]

How can I get started with this project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume by switching, you mean logic level translation. That is, you want to step 5V up to 12V.

The simplest solution would be a set of 5V SPST relays, connecting the coil to the switches and the NO (normally open) to the 12V and the output to the cruise control system.

If you want a cheaper and better solution you could consider using a transistor wired as a switch.

And be careful with auto electronics, if that doesn't go without saying.

**Possible transistor circuit:**

[image]

Comment: What would the circuit look like using transistors?  Also, would I just use a voltage regulator to get my <=5v supply for the switches?

Comment: A voltage regulator wouldn't really be an option for translating logic. It would be too slow. And you have to be careful of load dumps, which are voltage spikes produced when things in the car turn on and off (like the headlamps.) The spikes can be as high as +60V.

Comment: I'll draw up a circuit using transistors.

Comment: The reason I asked about the voltage regulator is that I don't currently have a +5v source.  I could probably find one but I'd rather just get it from the 12v if possible.  Also, I *think* the cruise kit is already doing some smoothing, since this 12v source normally powers a simple circuit including an LED and a few other components.

Comment: Yeah, there are probably regulators inside the unit. It will be a properly designed regulator able to handle such large load dumps, otherwise it wouldn't survive one day.

Comment: Right, and I wasn't planning to use anything from outside the unit.

Comment: Circuit added for transistors. It's probably a roundabout way of going about it, but it should work. (That is, it is doubly inverted.)

Comment: What program did you use to make that?

Comment: Falstad circuit sim: http://www.falstad.com/circuit/

Comment: Got it!  I was hoping to find a program like that.  Do you think I should even worry about scaling down the voltage, given that the current flowing through the switches is only ~10mA?

Comment: For my reference, your circuit spec is at http://pastebin.com/i6ePpfDG.

Comment: Well, I don't think that 10mA is going to be considerably dangerous current. And remember, worst case the wires burn out. AFAIK, the airbag is designed to not explode in a fire, so even if the wire starts getting warm near it should not present a problem.

Comment: Also remember most wires have a minimum rating of 500mA, I've typically seen 1A, so I don't think 10mA is going to cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

The potential safety issue is the current, not the voltage. You can use a resistor to limit the current so a short won't cause irritating fires. The control switches may not be expected to pass a significant amount of current but you can measure that with a multimeter.

Comment: A fuse sounds like a good idea.  My understanding is that I can't just use a resistor because that would drop the voltage below what the cruise kit is expecting.  Does that sound right?

Comment: Measure the current on the hand controls side. A resistor will cause a voltage drop per Ohm's law V = IR but if the current (I) is small compared to the size of the resistor it won't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Airbag requires about 6V only to set it off, so setting 5V as your ceiling is probably pushing it, I think I remember it needed less than 200mA, so a fuse is actually a waste of time, if not a bad placebo. I only know this because I once helped build an airbag tester to be used for Volkswagen and BMW on the Uitenhage plant in South Africa, AND had to wait patiently while everyone still messed about with antistatic gear (which I thought was overkill, but I may be wrong). The trouble with relays or switches, is that they need to have a good bit of juice running through the contacts, else they do not make good contact (they are designed to actually arc, and in low current applications, a small ceramic is used to sometimes make a tiny spark to weld the contacts together). DC is also not that great, since the arc carries metal with it.

So a transistor switching (boosting) circuit (which you have designed) is also getting my vote, you can use the transistors to drive a 12V relay (small one), ro regulators needed, and since car battery is 13.5V and the darlington-style circuit (which you drew) often looses just over a volt anyway. The voltage (and needed current) for the BASE of the darlington is going to be low enough to be safe. Just remember to place a diode across the relay coil for back EMF taking your transistors out.

Comment: Why are you saying that you would include a relay (actually I would need 3 of them) in addition to the transistor circuits?

Answer (score 0):

Why exactly are you concerned about 12V on those wires?

Its perfectly fine and doesn't represent any more or less danger than 5V would, or even GND honestly.

Comment: Short answer: because I don't know what I'm talking about :)  I don't want to take any risks with the thin wires running through the steering wheel area.  Since people here say it's the current I should worry about, I definitely want to limit it to a few mA.

Comment: even if its 20-22awg wire it can handle several amps without any danger.  If its short, like 3 feet, it can handle 10's of amps.  5V or 12V the draw is still going to be a few mA if that for most such applications.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you just need to convert the low voltage to a high voltage by use of a transistor switch. Using a BJT transistor will work, but I recommend using a MOSFET. They are more efficient and can handle more power without getting hot due to the very low "on" resistance. Consider this circuit:

[image: Automotive Voltage Converter]

The P channel MOSFET gate is pulled HI by RA, so it is turned "OFF." Remember, P channel transistors (or PNP) work opposite to that of N channel transistors (OR NPN). Since the FET is OFF, the outputs signal is pulled LO by RB.

If a switch is closed/pressed, then the FET gate is LO, turning the FET "ON." Now, the transistor acts like a switch, connecting the output to the 12V power source. There is a bit of loss in the transistor, but not a lot. Using a "Power MOSFET" is necessary to handle the level of current required to operate an automotive relay - not a problem since many of these transistors can switch dozens of amps.

Since the MOSFET is a voltage controlled device, only a negligible amount of current would be needed to control the transistor (this is the current through your steering wheel wires). A similar circuit could be made using an N channel MOSFET instead. See this website on using a MOSFET as a switch:

http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/tran_7.html

But realistically, this is all probably unnecessary. Have a look at the wire gauge table on this website:

http://www.powerstream.com/Wire_Size.htm

You will see that the few hundred mA needed to trip a relay are safely carried in wire size all the way down to 27 gauge (handles 288 mA). You should check those wires to see how big they actually are (usually printed on the side of the wire somewhere).